# Question on Definite integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sec x}{1+2\sin^2(x)}dx$$ ?
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.
I've tried simplifying the expression using trigonometry, and also applying properties of definite integrals but couldn't solve.

Comment: It would improve your Question to show what you've tried, e.g. a $u$-substitution or perhaps numerical integration to get a feeling for what the approximate answer is.  This gives Readers a better sense of what response will be useful to you.

Comment: Okay did it hardmath :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sec x}{1+2\sin^2(x)}dx$$
Substitute $u=\sin(x) \implies du=\cos(x) dx$
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\frac{du}{(1+2u^2)(1-u^2)}$$
Use fraction decomposition ..